# Using decorators to eliminate need for if statements in methods

Tags: python, decorator, metaclass

I have a class which stores some data from a file in it, but sometimes the file don't exist.

The class provides multiple methods to do calculations on data, but all those methods should raise error if no data is found.

This is an example of class and one of those methods:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        if isfile(file_name):
            with open(file_name) as f:
                self.data = json.load(f)
        else:
            self.data = None

   def get_something(self):
       if self.data is None:
          raise ValueError('no data')

       return data['a'] + data['b']
```

**Question**
How can I get rid of having an if statement in every class method. Is there a way to use decorators on the class or method level, which makes it look better than scattered if statements?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to have `A.__init__` raise immediately when there's no data, rather than setting `data = None` and having all the other methods raise later?  Not only does that give you fewer places where an exception needs to be raised, it gives the caller fewer places to handle them.

Comment: yea I am not sure actually, still thinking about this. However, the reason to keep it is there a couple of other methods which will still work and useful. The example here is simplified, and the class i have actually gets more than data file name

Comment: Are you able to write decorators *in general*? What actually is the sticking point?

Comment: @Samwise good to know that there's a vote against this approach, however still interested to know how this can be solved, regardless.

Comment: The sticking point is where to define the decorator, if it is a function, then it does not have access to the class's `self.data`. If i need to pass `self.data` the class is not instantiated yet, so how can it be done?

Comment: If you have some methods that depend on `data` and some that don't, I'd split the class along those lines, so that you only even attempt to load the data if you're going to do something that requires it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to have a decorator at the method level, define a wrapper function and look at the `self` argument to figure out what `data` is:

```
def requires_data(a_method):
    def wrapped_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(self, A), "only use this decorator on A methods"
        if self.data is None:
            raise ValueError('no data')
        return a_method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped_method


class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @requires_data
    def get_something(self):
        return self.data['a'] + self.data['b']


print(A({'a': 21, 'b': 21}).get_something())
print(A(None).get_something())  # raises!
```

As noted in the comments, though, I would instead favor having `data` be a required attribute, such that `__init__` raises immediately if it's not available:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, data):
        if data is None:
            raise ValueError('no data')
        self.data = data

    def get_something(self):
        return self.data['a'] + self.data['b']


print(A({'a': 21, 'b': 21}).get_something())
print(A(None).get_something())  # raises!
```

If the class has some functionality that depends on `data` and some that doesn't, and there are some cases where you want only the non-`data` functionality, split the class apart along those lines.